# How to validate IEnumerable<HttpPostedFiles> using Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/aX9D090113-File-upload-with-strongly-typed-view-and-model-validation.html) to create validation on `HttpPostedFileBase`, it works if I use `HttpPostedFileBase`, but if I changed to `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` for uploading multiple files, and submit the form the `ModelState.IsValid` is always false. I uploaded .png file and size is 914 bytes. How to use data annotation to validate multiple file upload?

My Model

```
public class BillingViewModel
{
     [Required]
     public long BillingID { get; set; }    
     public IEnumerable<TimeKeeper> TimeKeepers { get; set; }    
     [Required]
     [ValidateFile]
     public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> PostedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

ValidateFile.cs:

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 3; //3 MB
            string[] AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf" };
            var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;

            if (file == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Please upload Your Photo of type: " + string.Join(", ", AllowedFileExtensions);
                return false;
            }
            else if (file.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Your Photo is too large, maximum allowed size is : " + (MaxContentLength / 1024).ToString() + "MB";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are casting the property to the wrong type.

Change this:

```
var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
```

to:

```
var files = value as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;
```

and then you can iterate through each item in the collection and validate each file is the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
[Required]
public int? ListCount
{
 get {return PostedFiles == null || PostedFiles.Count()==0? (int?)null: PostedFiles.Count();}
}
```

Catch: Won't work on client side